# converting double to string in c#

Tags: c#

I am taking a coding class and I am trying to make calculator that where tips should be 15% of the check, and the lowest that can be tipped is $1. I want the results to go into a list box, but now im stuck on the last line. so far i have tried To.String() and using things other than double, but none of it has worked. I am new to coding so there is probably something i am overlooking.

```
        double tip, check;
        check = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        tip = check * 0.15;

        if (tip<1)
        {
            tip = 1;
        }
        lstOutput.Items.Add(String.Format(tip,check));
```

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with? Converting the double value to a string? Using that string as part of a longer string?  Something else?

Comment: I was having problems with converting the double value to a string, but it appears that i needed to format the string to get it working

Comment: But in your code you are converting string to double actually and then back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say what you want it to look like as the first parameter to string Format:

```
lstOutput.Items.Add(String.Format("tip is ${0:0.00} on a check of ${1}", tip,check));
```

Here we have a fixed string with some placeholders in. The tip is put in {0} and formatted to look like "x.xx", the check is put in {1} but not formatted. There is a risk that {1} could end up looking like 123.455689

In modern c# you can do the same thing in a more fluid, readable way:

```
lstOutput.Items.Add($"tip is {tip:0.00} on a check of {check}");
```

The dollar sign at th start of the string quotes means "interpolated string". C# will allow you to put actual variable names into the string literal. Visual studio will use colour highlighting to help you see whether you're "in the string" or "in code". You can do code in the brackets too:

```
lstOutput.Items.Add($"tip is {check * 0.15:0.00} on a check of {check}");
```